# How can I include *.ko files into vmlinux in a build time?

Tags: linux, kernel-module

Can I transform from `*.ko` to `*.o`?

I don't have any source code for `*.ko`.

My aim is to include `*.ko` into `vmlinux`.

Comment: @Hackaholic Please don't insert HTML markup into posts; Markdown is perfectly fine for the purpose you're trying to use it for.

Comment: This should be technically possible (after all, the kernel accomplishes it at runtime) but I doubt you will find any interest in supporting it - given the dim view of binary-only kernel modules it's doubtful there's much interest in supporting binary-only prelinked ones.  How come you don't have the source?

Comment: I got the module file from any vendor. They dont' want to share source code. But i can't use insmod for security isssue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From your question I understand that you are trying to convert the dynamic module `*.ko` into a static module `*.o` which is build into the kernel.

Simple answer to your question is `NO`
With out source code it is not possible.

If you have the source code of your module, then in the `Makefile` change `obj-m` to `obj-y` and link this Makefile to your kernel source before building by adding the path to your module's `Makefile` in the `Kernel Makefile`